# Error installing memcache using pear

Tags: memcached, pecl

I am trying to install memcache using pear but I am getting an error. The errors are something like this:

> downloading memcached-2.2.0b1.tgz ...
>   Starting to download memcached-2.2.0b1.tgz (70,216 bytes)
>   ..............
>   ...done: 70,216 bytes
>   15 source files, building
>   WARNING: php_bin /usr/local/php5/bin/php appears to have a suffix 5/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
>   running: phpize
>   sh: phpize: command not found
>   ERROR: `phpize' failed

i am using a godaddy shared hosting,

Does anyone already have a solution for this?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't install this on a shared account. Have you asked GoDaddy support if they will allow you to do it?

Comment: Yes, I did call godaddy, they do not install it, but is there any way, that I could install memcache extension?

Comment: Not unless you have root access, no.

Comment: when you say I have root access, is this the main user on my web hosting account?

Comment: No, I mean [**root**](http://www.linfo.org/root.html) as in "root user of the server" -- administrative control of the entire server. I would be very surprised if they let you install it, and you certainly can't do it without their blessing.

Comment: OMG, thanks for the insight Ed, looks like I have to find another option then.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is that GoDaddy won't allow you to install memcached on a shared hosting account.  You need root access to install memcached (sudo) and you can't have that on a shared hosting account.  I ran into this with Dreamhost once too, and 1and1.  I don't know of any shared hosts that will allow this.

Some options are to upgrade to a virtual server, or spin up a cloud instance on Amazon, Digital Ocean, or some other cloud service.  This would give you a private server that you could install anything you wanted on, including memcached.